# mvc need to call controller method from view without <form>

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms, methods

is there any other possibility to call a controller method in c# than using a form with an input element? Practically speaking I just want to execute a method by pushing a button or link.

so far I'm using:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("RefreshQuestion", "Admin"))
{ 
    <input type="submit" value="refresh" class="questionInput" />      
}
```

many thanks in advance
_tek

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is what you should do to call a controller method. If you don't want to use that code you can use an Action Link.

```
 @Html.ActionLink("Refresh", "RefreshQuestion", "Admin")
```

Do you need to post something as well or are you just making a call to the controller?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a little javascript to make an ajax call. You can pass data from your UI to your action method.

The below example will post the value of `Name` input element to the action method when user clicks on the button.

```
<input type="text" id="Name" />
<input type="submit" id="btnSave" value="refresh" class="questionInput" />
```

and your javascript is

```
$(function(){

  $("#btnSave").click(function(e){
     e.preventDefault();

     $.post("@Url.Action("RefreshQuestion","Admin")",
                                    { name : $("#Name").val() } ,function(data){
         // do something with the response
     });
  }); 

});
```

Your action method should have a parameter called `name` or a view model object which has a `name` property in it (model binding will do rest).

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Add(string name)
{
  // save and return something
}
```

You may also use the `serialize` method as needed to send the data filled in all the items in a form.